# Debian packaging: whats the difference between patches and changelog?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I am making a new package from a project that I've been working on for practice. I've been using git, and I've noticed similarities between it and the Debian packing system. What's confusing me is when I make a change to any of the files and do not manually update the `.orig.tar.xz` file, `dpkg` wants me to add a patch. Making patches is very annoying and the source code in the `.orig` is not updated so it's a nightmare to extract.

Now if I manually update `.orig.tar.xz` as well as make a new entry in changelog, it seems to be much more clean, it increments the build count as well (ie `3.2-2` -> `3.2-3`).

When should I use patch vs when should I update `.orig` and changelog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the now standard Debian source format 3.0 (quilt), the correct procedure when you make changes to the original/upstream source, is to add corresponding patches in the `debian/patches` directory, not to `.orig.tar.xz`. This is commonly [done using `quilt`](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2012/08/08/how-to-use-quilt-to-manage-patches-in-debian-packages/), but you can alternatively use a "proper" version control system like Git, if you want.

The Debian build system will automatically recreate the `.debian.tar.xz` based on the contents of the `debian` directory (including the `patches` subdirectory). The `.orig.tar.xz` file should not be modified. It's the upstream source.

And as for updating the changelog, that's up to you. Updating the changelog will increment the Debian version number. It has no direct bearing on patching the source.

Comment: So, if I was using git, whats the proper way to package the releases? Make a new package every time (in turn updating the `.orig.tar.xz` and not touching the patches)? It seems like what you're say is patches are used up until you want to permanently applying them all by doing a repackage. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SanchkeDellowar. I don't know enough about the context to answer. Are you packaging your own software, or someone elses? If it's your own software, you don't need Debian patches at all (i.e. patches in `debian/patches`). If the software is upstream, that's a different situation, and you might need patches. If you don't have a clear question to ask, we could talk in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat).